# Best way to add class to link with ui-sref?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What's the best way to add a class to link that uses `ui-sref="state1"`?
My issue is that I have my menu outside the `ui-view`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a data-ng-class="{active: active=='dash'}" data-ui-sref="dash">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-ui-sref="reports">Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-ui-view="main"></div>
```

I am trying to highlight the active link but not quite sure what the best method would be in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using the [`ui-sref-active`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) directive:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a ui-sref-active="active" data-ui-sref="dash">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-ui-sref="reports">Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-ui-view="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("[ui-sref='state1']").addClass('newClass');
}
$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

```css
.newClass{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a data-ng-class="{active: active=='dash'}" data-ui-sref="dash">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-ui-sref="reports" ui-sref='state1'>Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div data-ui-view="main"></div>
```